# Highcharts solid-gauge Error: c.color.tweenTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts

Highcharts solid-gauge Error: c.color.tweenTo is not a function
You can see the full stack of the error below.

Highcharts solid-gauge was working but now I only can see the chart without colors and next highchart element doesn't show.

```
 var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            height:150
        },

        title: '',

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickAmount: 2,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Stacktrace:

```
> Error: c.color.tweenTo is not a function
toColor@https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js:11:248
drawPoints/<@https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js:12:445
a.each@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:26:447
drawPoints@https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js:12:248
render@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:306:322
render@https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js:34:288
renderSeries/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:263:450
a.each@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:26:447
renderSeries@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:263:410
render@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:265:282
firstRender@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:268:382
init@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:244:321
getArgs@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:243:346
a.Chart@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:243:139
a.chart@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js:243:206
draw@http://localhost:9000/app/entities/math/math.controller.js:249:30
onSuccess@http://localhost:9000/app/entities/math/math.controller.js:226:24
resourceFactory/</Resource[name]/promise<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:821:18
processQueue@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16383:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16399:27
$eval@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17682:16
$digest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17495:15
$apply@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17790:13
done@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11831:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12033:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11966:9
```

HTML:

```
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need 3 scripts highcharts,highcharts-more and solid-gauge - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/

Comment: I have all of them. <script src="bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Take all files from same version of highchars..

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/

Helps me.